# splitstring by character inside form

Tags: c#, string, split

From my view, I try to pass a value looking like this `Page/33`,

The form looks like this:

```
<td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CreatePage", new { Id = item.Id})</td>
```

So in this case item.Id = Page/33 and I would like to split the string by the "/"-char. Only sending in whatever comes after the /, `33` in this case

Can I do this in a simple way inside the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IndexOf` method to find the character, and the `Substring` method to get the part of the string after it:

```
new { Id = item.Id.Substring(item.Id.IndexOf('/') + 1) }
```

Comment: That was EXACTLY what i was lookin for, tack!.
Will mark as answer asap.

Answer (score 1):

While the solution posted by Guffa works, here some more simple:

```
new { Id = item.Id.Split(new char[] {'/'}).Last() }
```